# Unable to run parallel apache httpd instances

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have created 2 conf files httpd.conf and httpd1.conf in my apache server. In order to run two instances of it.

When I try to start both apache instance

`httpd -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd1.conf -k start` and

`httpd -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf -k start` only one instance starts. I am able to run either first instance or second. But unable to run them parallel.
The error I am getting `httpd (pid 51415) already running`.

Where as a server should not have any problem in running multiple instance of any application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found problem. Every httpd service instance stores value of process id in separate file. Inorder to run every instance a new process id needs to generated. The location for process id file is defined in `httpd.conf`